# Need to add timestamp in log file which is generated using drool

Tags: java, jboss, drools

We are using a drools api. Need to add timestamp in Test.log. Below is the code.

```
 public static KStatefulSessionWrapper getNewStatefulKnowledgeSessionWrapper() throws Exception {
    KStatefulSessionWrapper ksessionWrapper = null;

    try {
        ksessionWrapper = new KStatefulSessionWrapper();
        StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = getKagent().getKnowledgeBase().newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
        ksessionWrapper.setStatefulKnowledgeSession(ksession);
        ksessionWrapper.setLogger(getKnowledgeRuntimeLoggerForSession(ksession));


    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(" StatefuleKnowledgeSesion can not be created "
                + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    System.out.println(" Session is created..");
    return ksessionWrapper;
}


 public static KnowledgeRuntimeLogger getKnowledgeRuntimeLoggerForSession(
        StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession) throws Exception {
    KnowledgeRuntimeLogger logger = KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory.newFileLogger(ksession, "Test");
    return logger;
}
```

Tried by setting global variable  in java file.

```
 ksession.setGlobal("logger", logger);

logger.info("Test"); // In drl file
```

Test is printed in server.log which is configured with log4j.

Below logs are being generated in Test.log

```
<org.drools.audit.event.ActivationLogEvent>
 <type></type>
 <activationId></activationId>
 <rule>rule number</rule>
<declarations></declarations>
```

Required output like below

```
 2016-10-03 13:26:44,533 GMT-00:00 <org.drools.audit.event.ActivationLogEvent>
 <type></type>
 <activationId></activationId>
 <rule>rule number</rule>
<declarations></declarations>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I made changes in drools-core-5.0.1.jar to add Timestamp.

Code is modified in writeToDisk method of WorkingMemoryFileLogger.java file. Below is existing code

```
     FileWriter fileWriter = null;
     fileWriter = new FileWriter(this.fileName + (this.nbOfFile == 0 ? ".log" : new StringBuilder().append(this.nbOfFile).append(".log").toString()), true);
     XStream xstream = new XStream();
     for (LogEvent event : this.events) {
        fileWriter.write(xstream.toXML(event) + "\n");
       }
```

Below is modified code

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS");;
 Date date=new  Date();
 String timestamp=sdf.format(date)+" GMT-00:00";
 FileWriter fileWriter = null;
 fileWriter = new FileWriter(this.fileName + (this.nbOfFile == 0 ? ".log" : new StringBuilder().append(this.nbOfFile).append(".log").toString()), true);
 XStream xstream = new XStream();

 for (LogEvent event : this.events) {
  String logevent=(xstream.toXML(event)).toString().replaceAll("[\r\n]", "");
    fileWriter.write(timestamp+" "+ logevent + "\n");
  }
```